# What's the math and intuition behind Smooth F1 Worley Noise?

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes, mathematics, source-code

I can't find any information nor article about it on the internet. The only thing I've got is [Blender's manual page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/voronoi.html).

If anyone could read the source code, please help me.

Thank you! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might have much better luck getting an answer at the Blender Developers forum: https://devtalk.blender.org/

Comment: Seems like just a blurred version that is included so that it's easier to make procedural materials just because of the way it looks. If you want a material like leather, or maybe some sort of stone wall it might be useful to have the voronoi 'islands' flat and the whole texture a bit smoother. Why do you ask? What's the context?

Comment: @curious_1 Thank you!

Comment: from Blender's documentation you can find wikipedia link, and "further reading" "references", and "external links", like this one https://www.carljohanrosen.com/share/CellNoiseAndProcessing.pdf

Comment: @lemon Thanks!!